# SQL to HQL Syntax how ? or can I use directly SQL but I also want result in JSON?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I want to convert this  SQL query into HQL :

```
SELECT count(*) as count, b.* 
FROM resource_view as a, 
resource as b 
where b._id = a.resource_id 
and a.class_id = '$id_class'
group by a.resource_id 
order by count desc limit 5
```

So what i have to do?

Comment: Add your hibernate entity classes to your post

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below example, the solution for convertion is available..

[Converting SQL to HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267085/converting-sql-to-hql)